# Matching a URL in iis rewrite rule

Tags: iis

Have an app that is hosted in iis in localhost/myapp, the idea is to redirect all urls matching "localhost/myapp/*.*" to "localhost/index1.htm" for a short while while its being updated. Using regex i'm trying to match the URL using "^myapp.*" but its not matching. It matches if we remove the '^' though, so whats wrong with "^myapp.*" as far as i know '^' means to start searching from the beginning of the path after "localhost/", i could be wrong, can anyone shed some light here, thanks.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="test" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^myapp.*" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="index1.htm" appendQueryString="true" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```